# How to use DataBindings for various objects in the collection?

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a collection of objects which has the following structure:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Guid { get; set; }
}

public class Child:Parent
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

List<Parent> collection ;
collection  = new List<Parent>();

collection.Add(new Parent());
collection.Add(new Parent());
collection.Add(new Child());
collection.Add(new Child());
collection.Add(new Parent());
```

So some elements are from Parent type and some from Child type(I have inheritance relationship among the objects in the collection).

I used the following bindings:

```
txtTitle.DataBindings.Add("Text", _BindingSource, "Title");
txtGuid.DataBindings.Add("Text", _BindingSource, "Guid");
txtDescription.DataBindings.Add("Text", _BindingSource,"Description");
```

First two bindings obviously work fine. But what should I do to the third one to display the data properly?

Comment: I haven't put any code for inserting into the collection. You can consider that we have the following insertions:

    collection  = new List<Parent>();
    
    collection.Add(new Parent());
    collection.Add(new Parent());
    collection.Add(new Child());
    collection.Add(new Child());
    collection.Add(new Parent());

Comment: Child is a children class for Parent. please try the code first then claim that it doesn't work.

Comment: the issue here is not the code for inserting data into the collection. Obviously I have the collection already that I asked about the binding.

Comment: I deleted previous comments as I'm tired right now and my explanation didn't come across well. By declaring the list as a List<Parent>, then unless you cast down to Child, you will in effect have Parents in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In his book "Data Binding with Windows forms 2.0", p. 125, author Brian Noyes says that items in a BindingSource must be homogenous, ie of the same type.

It would seem what you're trying to do is not possible, at least not with a BindingSource component.

Comment: Thanks, probably I have to merge all the classes into one.

Comment: Or you could have them implement the same Interface